# 3D Grid for multiple shapes

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

A few months ago I made a small terrain generator, like Minecraft, for a school project.
The way I did this was by using multiple chunks. Each chunk contained a 3-dimensional array that stored the blocks.
Every position in this array corresponded with the position of the block it contained.

```
blocks[x, y, z] = new Block();
```

Now I would like to add different sizes if blocks. However, I can't do that with the way I am storing the blocks right now, because bigger blocks would have to be spread over multiple positions in the 3-dimensional array.
An example of a game with different sizes of blocks (and different shapes) is LEGO Worlds. How does a game like this store all these little blocks?

I hope someone can help me with this.

The language I am using is Javascript in combination with WebGL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for *voxelization*?

Comment: I don't think this quallifies as voxelization because I don't want to use just blocks. I just want to know how to store an object on a 3D grid that is wider than 1 "position", like a door in Minecraft. Because it takes up more than 1 block.

Comment: The data structure depends on a multitude of factors - whether you want to save memory or computation time, how sparse / dense your world is, whether you want it to be open world / closed map

Comment: The best way to describe what it's gonna be is like Minecraft, but with the blocks being different sizes.

Comment: What *type* of voxel you have doesn't really affect what data structure you use, the latter being more affected by the *distribution* of voxels (a possible exception would be occlusion culling - well-tessellating voxels such as minecraft blocks typically don't need too much trickery)

Comment: You should be careful of converting between integer and world coordinates - the latter is usually in floating point. You should probably have a scaling constant for conversion between block indices and world coordinates.

Comment: Okay, so if I store a block that is 1x1x1 in a 3-dimensional array like this:

`blocks[x,y,z] = new Block();`

Then how do I store a block that is 2x1x2? The first thing that comes to mind is this:

`block = new Block();

blocks[x,y,z] = block;
blocks[x+1,y,z] = block;
blocks[x,y,z+1] = block;
blocks[x+1,y,z+1] = block;`

But that does seem a bit odd.

Comment: For a first project, you should probably store the block ID in each cell, and (maybe) store the list of cell ID's in each block; that may not scale so well to more advanced projects with larger worlds (particularly sparse ones - lots of memory waste)

Comment: Does that mean that every part of a block that is bigger than 1x1x1 has it's own ID? For example, if you were to store a Minecraft door, would the top of the door have a different ID than the bottom of the door?

Comment: No I mean *block ID* as in each separate voxel that forms a block links back to the same block (the one it belongs to); but that's just one interpretation - there can be many implementations I'm sure

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there are a few different ways of tackling an issue like this, but the one I'd recommend would depend on the amount of time you have to work on this and the scope (how big) you wanted to make this game.

**Your Current Approach**

At the moment I think your using what most people would consider the most straightforward approach by storing the voxels in a 3D grid

[[Source]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/voxel).

But two problems you seem to be having is that there isn't an obvious way to create blocks that are bigger then 1x1 and that a 3D grid for a world space is fairly inefficient in terms of memory usage (As for an array you have to have memory allocated for every cell, including empty space. JavaScript is no different).

**An Alternative Approach**

An alternative to using a 3D array would be to instead use a different data structure, the full name being a sparse voxel octree.

This to put it simply is a tree data structure that works by subdividing an area of space until everything has been stored.
[image: Quadtree]

The 2D form of this where a square sub divides into four smaller quadrants is called a quad tree and likewise a 3D equivalent divides into eight quadrants, called an octree. This approach is generally preferable when possible as its much more efficient because the trees only occupy more memory when its absolutely essential and they can also be packed into a 1D array (Technically a 3D array can be too).

A common tactic used with quad/octrees in some block based games is to take a region of the same kind of voxel that fit into one larger quadrant of the tree is to simply stop sub division there, as there's no reason to go deeper if all the data is the same.

The other optimization they can make is called sparse where regions of empty space (air) are simply deleted since empty space doesn't do anything special and its location can be inferred.

[[SVO Source]](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/88972/nvr-2010-001.pdf)

[[Z Order Curve Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)

**Recommended Approach**

Unless you have a few months to complete your game and you're at university I seriously wouldn't recommend an SVO (Though reading up about could impress any teachers you have). Instead I'd recommend taking the same approach that Minecraft appears to visibly has. E.G. A door is 1X2 but blocks can only be 1x1, then just make it two blocks.

In the example of a door you would have four unique blocks in total, two for the upper and lower half, and two variations of each being opened or closed.

E.G.

```
var cubeProgram; // shader program
var cubeVBO; // vertex buffer (I recommend combining vertex & UV coords)
var gl; // rendering context

// Preset list of block ID's
var BLOCK_TYPES = {
    DOOR_LOWER_OPEN: 0,
    DOOR_UPPER_OPEN: 1,
    DOOR_LOWER_CLOSED: 2,
    DOOR_UPPER_CLOSED: 3,
}

var BLOCK_MESHES = {
    GENERIC_VBO: null,
    DOOR_UPPER_VBO: null
    DOOR_LOWER_VBO: null
}

// Declare a Door class using ES6 syntax
class Door {
    // Assume X & Y are the lower half of the door
    constructor(x,y,map) {
        if (y - 1 > -1) {
            console.error("Error: Top half of the door goes outside the map");
            return;
        }

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        map[x][y  ] = BLOCK_TYPES.DOOR_LOWER_OPEN;
        map[x][y-1] = BLOCK_TYPES.DOOR_UPPER_OPEN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps a lot! I'm gonna try this first thing tomorrow. I do still have one question though. How do you think this is handled in LEGO Worlds? Because that game has much smaller bricks, and in different shapes too.

Comment: I'm not too sure but I think a good guess would be some sort of linear SVO that is split up into chunks.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of how that is done? I still don't quite understand what a SVO is and an example would really help me a lot.

Comment: An SVO just means sparse voxel octree. It'd just be an octree that maps to voxels with the branches to empty space being chopped off. I linked a good paper on the subject in my original answer [link](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/88972/nvr-2010-001.pdf) But I'd say doing it that way would be overkill unless this was for an undergraduate dissertation.

Comment: (Plus limitations in the version of GLSL WebGL uses makes implementing an SVO renderer very difficult)

Comment: You don't need an SVO renderer to use an SVO. Minecraft itself probably doesn't do anything fancy. It just builds a mesh based on the voxels for each NxN section of the world. That mesh is static and easily rendered using 20yr old standard methods of rendering. The mesh for a section is rebuilt anytime a new block is added/removed but then a single draw call will easily draw that section. I'm guessing [that's how this works](http://voxeljs.com/) though I haven't looked at the source